# CUPS with Google Cloud Print

Tags: 14.04, server, printing

I have a chromebook and I set up printers today to work with cups... But could I make a Google cloud print server with it? Is there an thing for Ubuntu server I can download through the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! After you set up your local USB or network printers, you go to the Ubuntu Software center and search "Google Cloud Print Server" and it will bring up "Server For Google Cloudprint" (or via the terminal `sudo apt-get install cloudprint`) and when it is complete type `sudo apt-get update` to update the current configuration. Then, once that is all done, type `sudo cloudprint` to run the application, then it should bring up a screen in FireFox or what ever browser you have, and then you make the USB printer you made with CUPS a Google Cloud Print Printer! Also keeping it as a Network Printer for you Mac and Windows devices!